# Xcode Failed with exit code 1でアプリケーションのビルドが出来なくなってしまいました。

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

`Xcode`で`macOS`アプリケーションを開発中にビルドが出来なくなってしまいました。
エラーログは以下の通りです。

```
/usr/bin/codesign -r- --display /Users/myAccount/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXXX-fqomebuyezdohfeijqknefdhtoik/Build/Products/Release/XXXXXX.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
Codesigning /Users/myAccount/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXXX-fqomebuyezdohfeijqknefdhtoik/Build/Products/Release/XXXXXX.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 29AD6A2BBB270A371E962B8E7E4C729F4E2917EB --verbose /Users/myAccount/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXXX-fqomebuyezdohfeijqknefdhtoik/Build/Products/Release/XXXXXX.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
/Users/myAccount/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXXX-fqomebuyezdohfeijqknefdhtoik/Build/Products/Release/XXXXXX.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib: replacing existing signature
/Users/myAccount/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXXX-fqomebuyezdohfeijqknefdhtoik/Build/Products/Release/XXXXXX.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib: A timestamp was expected but was not found.

error: Failed with exit code 1 (in target 'XXXXXX' from project 'XXXXXX')
```

`Derrived Data`の削除、プロジェクトのクリーン・オプション＋クリーンなどネットで見つけた方法はいくつか試してみたのですが、状況は変わりません。
どなたか、対処方法をご存じの方はおられませんでしょうか？

Comment: どの程度参考になるかわかりませんが、`A timestamp was expected but was not found`で検索したら、[こんな記事](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/8187)が見つかりました。要は最近会社のFirewall設定が変更になり、Appleのサーバとの通信の一部だけがうまくいっていなかったと言うことらしいです。Appleのサーバ自体の不具合と言う可能性も含めて、ネットワーク関連の問題という可能性は十分ありそうです。何か最近作業場所のネットワーク設定が変更になったと言ったことはないですか？

Comment: ヒントありがとうございます。残念ながらこちらのネットワーク設定は変更しておりません。OSが10.15.6/Xcode 11.6になったタイミングとも微妙にずれてますし。最悪OSのクリーンインストール＆証明書の再ダウンロードからの読み込み直しをしてみようかと思っています

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決しました。開発者証明書のプライベートキーが失われていたため発生したエラーでした。バックアップからプライベートキー付き証明書を再登録してビルドできるようになりました。